# Hiding disabled user accounts from distribution groups

Tags: active-directory, exchange, exchange-2010, groups

We have several users who are away for long periods of time (sometimes up to a year), and we disable their AD account when they leave.
This causes a problem, because the users might be in one or several security groups that are mail-enabled in Exchange 2010 (Distribution Groups).

Is it possible to hide the users from the Distribution Groups when the account is disabled?

NOTE: Not every user have an Exchange account, so the "Hide from global address list" isn't applicable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing I can think of is to remove the user accounts in question from the groups.

Personally, this is why I only use security groups to grant access to resources and distribution groups for email.

Comment: Yeah, this is also the only solution I've come up with, but it would be wonderful to not have redunant groups. +1 anyways :)